# Not working as it should attachBaseContext

Tags: java, android, xml

Tell me please, I encountered a problem on android 7 and above, if I make a fixed font in attachBaseContext, then when I rotate the screen, the width and height of the screen are not determined, it is always the same. How can this be fixed, or what's wrong with the code?

ps. You can look at this code on the emulator, on Android 7 and higher, when you rotate the screen, you will see that the width and height in Toast do not change.

Manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Code:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
override.fontScale = 1.3f;// fixed font
applyOverrideConfiguration(override);
}



//track screen rotation
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
Toast.makeText(this, "w - " + String.valueOf(this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()) + "\n" +
                "h - " + String.valueOf(this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight())
        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You override all configuration but not only fontScale.

```
final Configuration override = new Configuration();
override.fontScale = 1.3f;// fixed font
applyOverrideConfiguration(override);
```

According to official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createConfigurationContext(android.content.res.Configuration))

> A Configuration specifying what values to modify in the base
>   Configuration of the original Context's resources. If the base
>   configuration changes (such as due to an orientation change), the
>   resources of this context will also change except for those that have
>   been explicitly overridden with a value here.

Comment: So how to modify fontScale only?